# Can an asp.net razor PARTIAL page contain Javascript?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a simple Partial page in my asp.net Razor page but for some reason this is not being fired when rendered. Can scripts only be in the main pages and not partial pages?

```html
@section scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">
            alert('hello')
    </script>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following article has the answer https://www.adamrussell.com/asp-net-core-section-scripts-in-a-partial-view